# Contract call from a contract from a contract?

Tags: solidity, calldata, delegatecall

As I understand it, it is possible for a contract to call another contract by using

```
othercontractaddress.call(gas_amount).value(eth amount)(tx data).
```

Or in this case sender -> contract A -> contract B.

Is it possible to go one level deeper?

sender -> contract A -> contract B -> contract C?

Something like the following pseudocode?:

```
   othercontractaddress.call(gas_amount).value(eth amount)(thatothercontract.call(gas_amount).value(eth amount)(2ndtxdata))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, although obviously each contract has to execute the call itself. You can do this 1024 times until you reached the maximum depth. At that depth all new calls will fail. This even lead to vulnerabilities in the past.

That said, EIP-150 increased the gas cost of calls so much that you can't reach the maximum depth anymore.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would something like the call code I posted actually work or would it need to be tweaked?

Comment: No, you would have to define each call in the contract that should execute it. For example, in contract A you have `b_addr.call(gas_amount)`, then in contract B you have `c_addr.call(gas_amount)` and so on. You can't "condense" the calls into a single contract like in your code.

Comment: 1024 refers to the max local stack depth, of which every call will use more than 1 (up to 16 using solidity), so the max amount of nested calls is probably much less than 1024

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate? Why does a single call in solidity produce a call depth creater than 1?

Comment: Since he doesn't care to answer, here is my own view on this: it's incorrect. A call in solidity will increase the call depth exactly by one. Nothing I've seen indicates otherwise and it really wouldn't make any sense anyways. At the very least on EVM level this is definitely true: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/vm.py#L712: `msg.depth + 1` for a `CALL` instruction.

Comment: Can you please write a detailed answer? @mafrasi2

Comment: @ferit What other details are there? I think I've mentioned everything there is to say about this short of posting the actual code in the EVM implementations (well, I've linked to one). The EVM does *not* specify functions as the other user suggests, so the "intra contract" callstack of solidity has nothing to do with the "inter contract" callstack of the EVM.